# Output variable into html

Tags: javascript, html

How do I output javascript into the html below. I've been trying to get anything to display, but the only thing that displays is "object,object"

```
<h2>title</h2>
<ul>
  <li>rating</li>
  <li>year</li>
  <li>length</li>
  <li>comedy</li>
  <li>main characters</li>
 </ul>
```

Thank you for you help everyone. I really appreciate it.

Comment: you'll probably chuckle , but I've tried document.write(movieList[]);

Comment: why you are having the list in th script??

Comment: it's just for practice. This example is from a JavaScript book, but they don't give you a solution.

Comment: are you looking for a pure javascript answer?... I would suggest not attempting to reinvent the wheel and learn some library concepts in conjunction with the javascript. Life will be much easier. I tried the same thing when beginning in javascript. It's an uphill and hopeless battle is light of libraries. just learn not to depend on one over the other too much

Comment: yep, just pure javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure JavaScript can be a little nasty on the eyes sometimes:

```
for (var i = 0; i < movieList.length; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h2')).appendChild(document.createTextNode('title: ' + movieList[i].title));
    var cUL = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].rating));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].year));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].length));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].isComedy));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode('main characters: ' + movieList[i].mainCharacters.join(", ")));
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/27tbs/).

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer, but I would include that beyond being nasty on the eyes there are simpler ways of achieving this with the added bonus of having a great opportunity to add a tool to the toolbelt early!

Comment: @BrettWeber You mean jQuery? If so, I totally agree! Unless there are other constraints, plain JS sometimes is just not worth it...

Comment: @acdcjunior jQuery is my preference, yes, and I suppose I should have clarified that I meant a library in general, and [we are in no short supply of those!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries)

Answer (score 2):

make your list and items into a template and cloning using jquery so you can insert the data into the elements. It's a relatively simple pattern to produce.

```
var divContainer = $('#divContainer');

for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1 )
    divContainer.append
    ( 
        $('<ul></ul>').append
        (
            $('<li><li>').innerHtml(" prop Name " + array[i].propName)
        )
    );
```

[Since it seems you are just getting started, here is a good little reference to get you started in the right direction.](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/) I wouldn't rely on a book chapter by chapter to get where you want to go. It's tedious and unrealistic. Make a goal and do some research, take it a reasonable and applicable problem at a time instead of tackling the whole of the language right off.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Simple process for beginners. I would recommend OP reads the following links: http://json-template.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/Introducing-JSON-Template.html AND http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp

Answer (score 2):

Here is your HTML:

```
<body id="thebody">
<h2>title: Goodfellas</h2>
<ul>
  <li>rating: R</li>
  <li>year: 1990</li>
  <li>length: 3.25</li>
  <li>comedy</li>
  <li>main characters: James Conway, Henry Hill</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

HEre is your JS

```
var list = document.createElement("ul");

for (var key in movieList) {
    var title = document.createElement("li");
    var titleText = document.createTextNode("title: " +  movieList[key].title);
    title.appendChild(titleText);  
    list.appendChild(title);
}

 var _body = document.getElementById('thebody');
_body.appendChild(list);
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/wp4rY/) of course do this with every property

Comment: Since you didn't mentioned  jQuery, here is a pure JS solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution if you happen to be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

#### [Example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/p9Yux/)

```
// loop through the movie list.
$.each(movieList, function() {
    $('<h2>'+this.title+'<h2>').appendTo('#movies');
    $('<ul>').appendTo('#movies');
    $('<li>'+this.rating+'</li><li>'+this.year+'</li><li>'+this.length+'</li><li>'+this.isComedy+'</li>').appendTo('#movies');
    // open the main characters list item.
    var charLi = '<li>main characters: ';
    $.each(this.mainCharacters, function() {
        charLi += this + ', ';
    });
    // remove the extra comma and space.
    charLi = charLi.substring(0, charLi.length - 2);
    // close the list item.
    charLi += '</li>';
    $(charLi).appendTo('#movies');
    $('</ul>').appendTo('#movies');
});
```